# Travis-ci boost log compilation with biicode time-out

Tags: boost, travis-ci, boost-log, biicode

I am using travis-ci and biicode to build my project who is depending on boost log. But boost log times are longer than 10 min so I get this message:

```
No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a
stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
The build has been terminated
```

The build is working correctly, it's just that boost log is really long to compile with limited resources (I tried to compile it on a VM with 1 CPU and 2GB of RAM and it took almost more than 15 min)

I know this is happening because there is not enough verbose going on so I tried the following flags:

1. >bii cpp:build -- VERBOSE=1
2. In the CMakeList.txt, set BII_BOOST_VERBOSE ON as mentionnened [here](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/examples/boost.html?highlight=boost)
3. Set BOOST_LOG_COMPILE_FAST_ON as explained [here](http://torjo.com/log2/doc/html/macros.html#macros_compile_time_fast)
4. Using [travis_wait](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-timeouts/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received)

Actually travis_wait seems to be the correct solution but when I put it in my .travis.yml like this

```
script: travis_wait bii cpp:build
```

It does actually doesn't output logs like usually and just time out after 20 min. I don't think the actual building is taking place

What is the correct way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, Boost.Log takes a long time to compile.

You can use `travis_wait` to call `bii cpp:configure`, but I'm with you, I need log feedback (No pun intended). However, I have tried that too and leaded to >50min build, which means travis aborts build on free accounts :( Of course my repo does not build Boost.Log only.

Just as a note, here's part of the `settings.py` file from the [`boost-biicode`](https://github.com/Manu343726/boost-biicode) repo:

```
#Boost.Log takes so much time to compile, leads to timeouts on Travis CI
#It was tested on Windows and linux, works 'ok' (Be careful with linking settings)
if args.ci: del packages['examples/boost-log']
```

I'm currently working on a solution, launching asynchronous builds while printing progress. Check [this issue](https://github.com/Manu343726/boost-biicode/issues/3). It will be ready for this week :)

To speed-up your build, try to play with `BII_BOOST_BUILD_J` variable to set the number of threads you want for building Boost components. Here's an example:

```
script:
- bii cpp:configure -DBII_BOOST_BUILD_J=4
```

Be careful, more threads means more RAM needed to compile at a time. Be sure you don't make the travis job VM go out of memory.